# Java Array initialization with type casting

Tags: java, casting, array-initialization

The following code makes me confused:

```
Object[] arr1 = new String[]{"a", "b", "c"};
Object[] arr2 = {"a", "b", "c"};

String[] a = (String[]) arr1; // ok
String[] b = (String[]) arr2; // ClassCastException

System.out.println(arr1.getClass().getName()); // [Ljava.lang.String;
System.out.println(arr2.getClass().getName()); // [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

I am trying to understand why the two initialization are different from each other. The first one is a post declaration, while the second one is a shortcut. The two are both declared as `Object[]`

My naive understanding is that:

```
Object[] arr2 = {"a", "b", "c"}; // is a syntax sugar of
Object[] arr2 = new Object[] {"a", "b", "c"};
```

So the runtime type of `arr2` is exactly `Object[]` which can not be converted into `String[]`.

But the things get strange here, because Java Array is covariant:
`String[]` is a subclass of `Object[]` and `arr2` is exactly a `String[]`, casting back from `Object[]` to `String[]` on `arr2` should work.

Any explanation on this is high appreciated.

Comment: _"arr2 is exactly a String[]"_ It's an `Object[]`. It appears that they are only strings in it, but it stills an `Object[]`. Try to do `arr1[1] = 1;`, you will have an `ArrayStoreException` at runtime as it's really a `String[]` behind, but `arr2[1] = 1;` works fine as it's an `Object[]`.

Answer (score 6):

Because `arr2` is an `Object[]`, there's nothing stopping you from writing

```
arr2[0] = new Object();
```

right before your cast, case in which the cast would no longer make sense anyway.

Because of the way initializer syntax works, also note the following:

```
Object x = {"a", "b"}; // error: illegal initializer for Object
Object[] a = {"a", "b"}; //a has class [Ljava.lang.Object; 
String[] b = {"a", "b"};  //b has class [Ljava.lang.String;
```

The compiler determines whether you want your array to be an `Object[]` or a `String[]` based on your declaration.

Comment: There's also nothing stopping you from writing `arr1[0] = new Object();`.

Answer (score 5):

> arr2 is exactly a String[]

No, it isn't - it's an `Object[]`, as you said - your line is equivalent to:

```
Object[] arr2 = new Object[] {"a", "b", "c"};
```

It's an `Object[]` which *happens* to have elements which are all string references at the moment... but you could also write:

```
arr2[0] = new Object(); // Fine, because arr2 is an Object[]
```

If you did the same thing with `arr1`, you'd get an exception:

```
arr1[0] = new Object(); // Fine at compile time, will throw an exception
```

You can check the *actual* execution-time type of an object using `getClass` of course:

```
System.out.println(arr2.getClass());
```

Answer (score 3):

Almost correct. Your logic is flawed here:

```
arr2 is exactly a String[]
```

No, it is not. It is an array of Objects. The fact that you just added Strings into this array is meaningless. You could have written

```
arr2 = {"a", new Integer(5) };
```

too.

Probably that makes it more clear, why you are not allowed to cast such an array to String[].

Answer (score 1):

```
Object[] arr2 = {"a", "b", "c"};
```

In this case, the array you declared is equal to

```
Object[] arr2 = new Object[] {"a", "b", "c"};
```

So, the elements in arr2 can be any type of `Object`. And at the line

```
String[] b = (String[]) arr2; // ClassCastException
```

Because you are trying cast whole `Object[]` to a `String[]`.

Where as in the first you are explicitly telling all the Objects are Strings

```
Object[] arr1 = new String[]{"a", "b", "c"};
```